# Pandas jumbling up data after selecting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (2.3m x 33) size dataframe. As I always do when selecting columns to keep, I use

```
colsToKeep = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
df = df[colsToKeep]
```

However, this time the data under these columns becomes completely jumbled up on running the code. Entries for row A might be in row D for example. Totally at random.

Has anybody experienced this kind of behavior before? There is nothing out of the ordinary about the data and the df is totally fine before running these lines. Code run before problem begins:

```
with open('file.dat','r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)

#rename columns with the first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

#drop first row which is now duplicated
df = df.iloc[1:]

#. 33 nan columns - Remove all the nan columns that appeared    
df = df.loc[:,df.columns.notnull()]

colsToKeep = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
df = df[colsToKeep]
```

Data suddenly goes from being nicely formatted such as:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

to something more random like:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
7  9  3  4  5  1  2  8  6
3  2  9  2  1  6  7  8  4
2  1  3  6  5  4  7  9  8
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, repeatable example, or at least a sample of your input and output DF's?

Comment: You can use `df.reindex(colsToKeep, axis=1)` to get that order back at anytime.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't seem to work which makes me think maybe its an issue with the column naming.

Comment: @scnerd I would love to provide a reproducible examples but I am entirely unsure what is causing the problem to do so! I did give a more detailed description however.

Comment: What version of python is this?

Comment: @roganjosh 3.7.1

Comment: I am also wondering why on my file, when I expected 33 columns, there were an additional 33 labelled as 'NaN for col names and data in the rows was none. Issue could be here perhaps?

Comment: Then i really cant think what would cause this because my only guess was dictionary ordering, which is used under the covers. You should be able to provide an MCVE despite not knowing the cause; if you're unable to do so with the kinda of data you've shown then the issue must be external to this

Comment: @roganjosh I'm totally stumped. There is absolutely nothing out of the ordinary with the code. The only unusual part is when I open the .dat file with Excel, I find there are 33 columns. Importing it to a df with Pandas yields an extra 33 NaN columns which I must remove. 

Unfortunately the data is sensitive so I cannot really share. I was merely troubleshooting. But thank you for your input.

Comment: @CiaranOBrien Can you create some dummy data that replicates this problem?